# Create PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE_ARRAY for IShellItemArray

Tags: c++, winapi, com, windows-8

I have to call [IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateForProtocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/hh706905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for opening a Windows 8 app, therefore I have to provide `IShellItemArray*` data.

Basically, I just want to create a new `IShellItemArray`, so I try to call [SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But I do not *really* know which type the second parameter has. MSDN says:

> rgpidl [in]
>     Type: PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE_ARRAY
>       A list of cidl constant pointers to ITEMIDLIST structures.

I can't find nowhere information about this type. Not in MSDN, not in my favorite search engine.

I would be glad if someone could clarify this type and its creation/initialization or could provide some sample code.

Comment: Did you follow the link to [the `ITEMIDLIST` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773321.aspx) in the documentation you mention above? It explains how `ITEMIDLIST` works and what `IDLIST_ABSOLUTE` represents.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I did but the documentation was still not clear as the response by Jonathan now. These MSDN pages simply lack of sample code which is in my opinion a bit easier to follow than  continuous text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE_ARRAY` is equivalent to `LPCITEMIDLIST *`, i.e. an array of constant pointers to ITEMIDLISTs (otherwise known as PIDLs). The 'ABSOLUTE' part of the typedef indicates that the PIDLs must be absolute (that is, a fully qualified PIDL beginning at the desktop) rather than child PIDLs (relative to some folder).

You can create one the same way you make any array, e.g.

```
PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pIdlArray[10];
pIdlArray[0] = myFirstPidl;
pIdlArray[1] = mySecondPidl;
...
```

The reason for the different typedef is the `STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS` define. If this symbol is defined the shell API headers switch to using "typed" PIDL pointers, which makes it much more obvious when you're meant to use an absolute PIDL, a child PIDL, a const PIDL, etc. If `STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS` is not defined, you can use LPITEMIDLIST and its variants everywhere.

Comment: You are declaring an array of `PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE_ARRAY` values, which is not correct.  You need to declare an array of `PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE` values instead: `PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pIdlArray[10];`

Comment: Of course you're right, thanks. My only defense is I haven't had my morning coffee yet!